# Two groups of individuals are playing two socially distanced games, but need to share a single $5$-sided fair die.

Tags: probability, expected-value

To be honest I don't even know how to begin to solve this problem. Can anyone help and guide me? It will be appreciated.

*Problem Statement:*

Two groups of individuals are playing two socially distanced games, but need to share a single $5-sided$ fair die to roll until a specific roll is achieved, which is different for each player. The players have to roll the die for themselves (a player cannot roll for others). Due to disinfecting protocol, the die can be rolled once a minute, at the beginning of the minute.

Player $A$ from group $1$ takes the die to roll a $5$ with the first roll at $10:01$

Player B (needs a roll of a $1$ or a $2$) from group $2$ is ready to start rolling at 10:04 (in time for the roll at $10:04$)

*Answer The Following:*

$1$. At what time is player $B$ expected to be finished with the die?

$2$. Player $D$ from group $2$ did not have to wait for player $C$ from group $1$ to finish rolling a $\leq3$ roll. This means that player $C$ must have taken $3$ or less rolls to do so.
What is expected number of rolls it took player $C$ to roll a $\leq3$

Comment: Are these problems from a probability class/book?  If so, what was your training in the class/book, just prior to the problems?

Comment: (`$...$` does not mean italics. For that you can use `*...*`)

Comment: @user2661923 I don't know the book. It was in random exercise notes of probability, I downloaded from google for practice. I was solving each question in those notes. This one seems a bit tricky, I don't know how to do it. Please help me.

Comment: what means "to finish rolling $a\leqslant 3$"?

Comment: @Masacroso $a$ here is an article from English Grammar. Don't consider it as some variable or parameter. Hence the question means the finishing roll will result either in $1$ $2$ or $3$ ($\leq3$). Did you get the question now?